# Adding a new server to the farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, web-services, front-end

I am currently trying to add a new web front end server to my SharePoint Farm. However I am faced with an issue, the update 'SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2899494)' is present in my farm, so in order to join a server to the farm i need to install this same update in my new server, but the update is no longer available from Microsoft.
What can I do to get this update?

Comment: can you install the latest Microsoft Office update. as suggested [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/2899494/november-11-2014-update-for-sharepoint-server-2013-kb2899494)?

Comment: I have not been able to though, updates are failing to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the update is unavailable, you will need to patch your current farm to a higher patch level (if that is the last update you've applied, you should be applying this months patches to prevent a potential compromise of your farm). I would suggest applying the June 2020 cumulative update.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, can you throw more light on the aspect of preventing compromise

Comment: I would suggest reading the vulnerabilities that SharePoint patches are resolving. For example, the last couple of months a bad actor can create a workflow which executes code as the account running the IIS Application Pool.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary new farm when installing the SharePoint Server. Then install the SharePoint patch(KB28994940). After updating, run the configuration wizard to disconnect the server from the farm. Finally join this server to your farm.

Comment: My problem is that I cant find the patch KB2899494 to download on Microsoft or anywhere else. I need to install this patch but I cant find it to download, I hope you understand my situation.

Comment: if you patch the farm to the same version number it should allow you to add the new server